# Docker - ELK stack -- "Elasticsearch appears to be uneachable or down"

Tags: elasticsearch, docker, docker-compose, elasticsearch-plugin

So I am using docker-compose to launch the ELK stack, which will be filled by filebeats... my config is something like this:

```
elasticsearch:
  image: elasticsearch:latest
  command: elasticsearch -Des.network.host=_non_loopback_
  ports:
    - "9200:9200"
    - "9300:9300"
logstash:
  image: logstash:latest
  command: logstash -f /etc/logstash/conf.d/logstash.conf -b 10000 -w 1
  volumes:
    - ./logstash/config:/etc/logstash/conf.d
  ports:
    - "5044:5044"
  links:
    - elasticsearch
  environment:
    - LS_HEAP_SIZE=2048m
kibana:
  build: kibana/
  volumes:
    - ./kibana/config/:/opt/kibana/config/
  ports:
    - "5601:5601"
  links:
    - elasticsearch
```

My logstash.conf file looks something like this:

```
input {
    beats {
      port => 5044
    }
}

....

output {
  elasticsearch {
      hosts => "localhost:9200"
      manage_template => false
      index => "%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
      document_type => "%{[@metadata][type]}"
    }
  }
```

These docker containers are running on the same instance and I have confirmed being able to hit both ports externally.

The error which appears during a sync of a file from filebeat is:

```
logstash_1       | {:timestamp=>"2016-05-19T19:52:55.167000+0000", :message=>"Attempted to send a bulk request to Elasticsearch configured at '[\"http://localhost:9200/\"]', but Elasticsearch appears to be unreachable or down!", :error_message=>"Connection refused", :class=>"Manticore::SocketException", :client_config=>{:hosts=>["http://localhost:9200/"], :ssl=>nil, :transport_options=>{:socket_timeout=>0, :request_timeout=>0, :proxy=>nil, :ssl=>{}}, :transport_class=>Elasticsearch::Transport::Transport::HTTP::Manticore, :logger=>nil, :tracer=>nil, :reload_connections=>false, :retry_on_failure=>false, :reload_on_failure=>false, :randomize_hosts=>false, :http=>{:scheme=>"http", :user=>nil, :password=>nil, :port=>9200}}, :level=>:error}
```

Thanks,

Comment: Where do you get error? Is there a more info about error?

Comment: @alpert -- The error comes when passing in a log file (166mb) via beats to logstash, logstash can't seem to find Elasticsearch.   The error (in the title) appears during when I try to sync from my local machine -> logstash on the machine running docker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to reach elasticsearch on localhost, but it's not possible, in this case localhost is the docker container containing logstash.

You have to access it via the link :

```
output {
 elasticsearch {
  hosts => "elasticsearch:9200"
  manage_template => false
  index => "%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
  document_type => "%{[@metadata][type]}"
 }
}
```

or, if you want to access your elasticsearch instance from "outside" instead of localhost, fill your ip (not 127.0.0.1)

Comment: Ahhhh, okay, that makes total sense... Let me give it a go.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I was banging my head against that for a while.